# How to play a complete prompt and do a CURL request at the backend?

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

The callflow I want to build:

1. Play Welcome Prompt (5 seconds)
2. Do a CURL request to an API based on the callerId number
3. Based on the response of step 2, play another prompt or hangup the call

**Problem**

The Curl request may take upto 3 seconds of delay, I want to play the prompt and want to do a CURL request simultaneously, I have tried MOH, but the problem with MOH is that it stops playing the prompt when the CURL response is recieved. Actual callflow is:

```
exten => 1002,1,Progress()
exten => 1002,n,StartMusicOnHold(T1)
exten => 1002,n,Set(CURL_RESULT=${CURL(http://192.168.0.38/test.php?aparty=${CALLERID(num)})})
exten => 1002,n,NoOp(isSubscriber:${CURL_RESULT})
exten => 1002,n,GotoIf($["${CURL_RESULT}"!="0"]?lbl_call_hangup:)
exten => 1002,n,StopMusicOnHold(T1)
exten => 1002,n,Playback(welcome)
exten => 1002,n,Read(DTMF,,0,n,1,10)
exten => 1002,n,Hangup
```

What I want is to playing complete prompt and while playing the prompt, do the curl request at the backend. There is another solution we have tried which is to write a wrapper for this API call which returns immediately and another API call to get the result.

Here is what we built:

1. Do CURL request to wrapper which returns immediately
2. Play Welcome Prompt
3. Do CURL request to get the response of the initial request done in step 1
4. -do the rest of the things-

But the problem in this callflow is that the wrapper has to keep the request/response pair in memory, have to do alot of house keeping in case the call drops during step 2 etc.

**Question**

So is there a way in the dialplan to achieve playing of prompt and doing a curl request in the meanwhile.

PS: Using astersik 13.18.3

Answer (score 0):

Can recommend you read book, for example ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"

Possible solutions:

1) use dial and Local channel with 'm' param for hold music. In local context where you dial do curl

2) use AGI and "SET MUSIC ON/OFF"

3) use  curl in background thread.

4) use Background app.

BTW, if call drop while dooing curl request anyway you get unpredictable result. You have care about that yourself(transaction,confirmation etc)